# Loading data into oracle table using Kafka jdbc sink

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to load the data from Kafka to Oracle using JDBC sink connector to replicate the example mentioned in the confluent website:

https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html

```
        name=jdbc-sink
        connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
        tasks.max=1

        # The topics to consume from - required for sink connectors like this one
        topics=orders

        # Configuration specific to the JDBC sink connector.
        # We want to connect to a SQLite database stored in the file test.db and 
        auto-create tables.
        #connection.url=jdbc:sqlite:test.db
        connection.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXXX:XXXX/XXXXX
        connection.user=XXXX
        connection.password=XXXXX
        auto.create=true
        auto.evolve=true
        pk.mode=record_value
        insert.mode=insert
        pk.fields=id
        #fields.whitelist=product,quantity,price
        batch.size=0
```

error

```
# ./confluent status jdbc-sink
    {"name":"jdbc-sink","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"10.87.40.165:8083"},"tasks":[{"state":"FAILED","trace":"org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:517)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:288)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Cannot ALTER to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, name='product', isPrimaryKey=false}, as it is not optional and does not have a default value
            at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.amendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:137)
            at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.DbStructure.createOrAmendIfNecessary(DbStructure.java:73)
            at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.BufferedRecords.add(BufferedRecords.java:78)
            at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcDbWriter.write(JdbcDbWriter.java:66)
            at io.confluent.connect.jdbc.sink.JdbcSinkTask.put(JdbcSinkTask.java:69)
            at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:495)
            ... 10 more
    ","id":0,"worker_id":"10.87.40.165:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

I am able to see the data consumed using consumers but data is not being loaded in oracle table. I changed the topic name to UPPERCASE and tried but still it didn't work. I have added the `auto.evolve=true` option as well but it didn't work.
There are similar posts found here I went through it without much help.

I am just doing auto create of table. I can see table created in oracle but no data.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your stacktrace, here is the error:

```
Cannot ALTER to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{STRING}, 
name='product', isPrimaryKey=false}, as it is not optional and does not have 
a default value
```

So the data that you're trying to load has the field `product` in it, with no default, and your target table doesn't have that column.

Comment: No it's not missing i can see the table for created with all the fields.Here is the DDL for it                                                                                                           CREATE TABLE "orders" 
   ( "product" CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "quantity" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "price" BINARY_FLOAT NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "id" NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 
  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE
   )

Comment: It’s coming through as a `STRING` and you’ve defined it as a `CLOB` - that may cause the problem you’re seeing. Change the DDL (or your source schema) and see if that helps

Comment: I am able to resolve it by adding "default value" for the fields.                           {"name":"product", "type": "string", "default":"aaa"}. I have defined as "string" in my source but while creating the table it is creating as "CLOB" not sure how should i create as "string"? I have given option as auto-create